# Can I detect both landscapes in android?

Tags: android, rotation, landscape

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect landscape left (normal) vs landscape right (reverse) with support for naturally landscape devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088856/how-to-detect-landscape-left-normal-vs-landscape-right-reverse-with-support-f)

Is it possible to detect one landscape vs the other landscape when rotating the device?

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

works but I'd like to see if I can determine which side of the phone it is on as I want to display a different layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, for devices running Android 2.2+.  Check out [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/one-screen-turn-deserves-another.html) for the details or you can [skip to the punchline](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation%28%29).

Comment: perfect, I am creating for 2.2+, what goes in front of `getRotation()` ? I tried `this.getRotation();` but says that method isn't available for my class

Comment: Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int orientation = display.getRotation();