# Android: stack of disabled orientation changes

Tags: android, android-orientation

My application is designed to be "landscape-only". Rotation between left and right landscape must be supported so I am using `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"`.

However, there's a mini-game in my app when rotation must be disabled completely (because this mini-game is to be controlled by device tlting). After mini-game has finished, orientation handling policy must be restored back to `sensorLandscape`.

The standard method to disable orientation change is to call

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```

But not in the case! As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611457/android-temporarily-disable-orientation-changes-in-an-activity#comment4357118_3614089) (and checked by me), it leads to orienation change to default state (that may be portrait).

Hence, the only way to go from `sensorLandscape` to "disableRotation" is to set explicitly desired orientation. So I have a choice: either call

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

or

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
```

Obviously, I need to pass a current orientation, but it seems that Android has no function to get it!

`getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` returns either `Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` or `Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` that is of no use.

`getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()` seems to be more promising. It returns `Surface.ROTATION_0` ... `Surface.ROTATION_270` and I tried to use a logic as follows:

```
int getCurrentOrintation()
{
    final int rot = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    if (Surface.ROTATION_0 == rot || Surface.ROTATION_90 == rot)
    {
        return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    }
    return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
}
```

It works fine on Google Nexus, but returns flipped oreintation on Kindle Fire HD.

So, is it possible in principle to temporarily lock orientation change in Android?

Comment: Are you using a seperate activity for the mini game?

Comment: @Submersed No. Anyway, how could it help if I did use a separate activity?

Answer (score 1):

You can lock orientation for specific activities by declaring `screenOrientation="locked"` in your android manifest, or by using the programmatic equivalent - `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED`.  However, this was added in API level 18, so it's limited to new devices.  See the  manifest [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) for more info.

Comment: Yes, `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED` seems promising (though I did not try it). But as you mentioned API level 18 is a stop-sign for me. I have to support API level >= 10.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing the orientation does not disable the accelerometer / gyroscope sensors, so you shouldn't need to remove the orientation lock.

You should however note that the values given by the sensors are in a standard sensor coordinate system:

> Accelerometers use the standard sensor coordinate system. In practice, this means that the following conditions apply when a device is laying flat on a table in its natural orientation:
>
> If you push the device on the left side (so it moves to the right), the x acceleration value is positive.
> If you push the device on the bottom (so it moves away from you), the y acceleration value is positive.
>
> If you push the device toward the sky with an acceleration of A m/s2, the z acceleration value is equal to A + 9.81, which corresponds to the acceleration of the device (+A m/s2) minus the force of gravity (-9.81 m/s2).
>
> The stationary device will have an acceleration value of +9.81, which corresponds to the acceleration of the device (0 m/s2 minus the force of gravity, which is -9.81 m/s2).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but it does not answer my question that is "How do I lock device orienation?".

Comment: Your minigame requires the device to be turned 180 degrees?

Comment: My minigame does not want to be turned upside down when player tilts his device. And yes, device tilting is a part of gameplay in this minigame.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code to get the current orientation and lock it.

```
        int currentOrient = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (currentOrient == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
        {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);//Lock to Landscape mode
        }
        else
        {
           setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);//Lock to Potrait mode
        }
```

Comment: `currentOrient` is always `Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` in my case. I need to know whether it is `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` or `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE`.

Comment: Have you gone through this stack post .
Try going through the blog link and see if it helps
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6021094/855303

Comment: They suggest to use `getRotation`. It does not work in general case. I have checked it -- see last paragraph in my question.