# Android Screen/Camera Orientation: Landscape Right/Left vs Portrait Up/Down

Tags: java, android, orientation, android-windowmanager

How to distinguish between Landscape (Right/Left) vs Portrait (Up/Down) on android? I tried:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

and it always returns Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT.

also, I checked:

[How to detect landscape left (normal) vs landscape right (reverse) with support for naturally landscape devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088856/how-to-detect-landscape-left-normal-vs-landscape-right-reverse-with-support)

[Check orientation on Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone)

I tried the onConfigurationChanged as well. I cannot get Right vs Left on landscape mode (up vs down on portrait).

**Is there a clean way of finding this on Android 5.0+?**

**Note:** My activity could be launched with any orientation. Capturing orientation changes using a listener may not be viable since I want the real orientation of the phone (even before I get a callback on orientation changes).

Also, by default:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

**Note:** My activity responds to auto-rotate changes.